# 'dependencies.dependency.version' for jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar must be a valid version

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependencies, pom.xml

I have to make a Soap web service, but I get stuck right away, I can't pass the configuration stage.

I was solving a lot of configuration problems which is apparently the way of Java, and now, a new one comes out:

> 'dependencies.dependency.version' for jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar must be a valid version

I tried what other post said and now:

> Could not resolve dependencies for project com.javaspringclub:SpringBoot_SOAP_WebServices_Movies:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

This is my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.javaspringclub</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBoot_SOAP_WebServices_Movies</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringBoot_SOAP_WebServices_Movies</name>
    <description>WebService Example</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <!--groupId>package1</groupId>
            <artifactId>package1</artifactId>
            <version>${package1.version}</version -->
                <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <!--version>${jakarta-xml-api.version}</version-->
            <version>2.0</version>          
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc-schema</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/main/resources/xsd/movies.xsd</source>
                    </sources>
                    <packageName>com.javaspringclub.gs_ws</packageName>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

The problem occurs here:

```
 <!--groupId>package1</groupId>
                <artifactId>package1</artifactId>
                <version>${package1.version}</version -->
                    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
                <!--version>${jakarta-xml-api.version}</version-->
                <version>2.0</version>
```

I'm a programmer of other technologies, any help will be appreciated

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1:xjc (xjc-schema) on project SpringBoot_SOAP_WebServices_Movies: Execution xjc-schema of goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1:xjc failed: A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1:xjc: com/sun/codemodel/CodeWriter
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/jaxb2-maven-plugin/2.3.1/jaxb2-maven-plugin-2.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.11/jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-core/2.2.11/jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-xjc/2.2.11/jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-jxc/2.2.11/jaxb-jxc-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0-M3/qdox-2.0-M3.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.3.0/sisu-inject-bean-2.3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guava/0.9.9/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.13.1/aether-util-1.13.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.5/plexus-compiler-api-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.7/plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : com.sun.codemodel.CodeWriter
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

After 2.3.2

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1:xjc (xjc-schema) on project SpringBoot_SOAP_WebServices_Movies: Execution xjc-schema of goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1:xjc failed: A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1:xjc: com/sun/codemodel/CodeWriter
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/jaxb2-maven-plugin/2.3.1/jaxb2-maven-plugin-2.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.11/jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-core/2.2.11/jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-xjc/2.2.11/jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-jxc/2.2.11/jaxb-jxc-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0-M3/qdox-2.0-M3.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.3.0/sisu-inject-bean-2.3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guava/0.9.9/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.13.1/aether-util-1.13.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.5/plexus-compiler-api-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.7/plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : com.sun.codemodel.CodeWriter
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Comment: If you look up [`jakarta.xml.bind`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api):[`jakarta.xml.bind-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api) in the **MVN Repository**, you'll see that there is no version `2.0`. There is a version `2.3.3` if you want to try that. --- There is a version `2.2.11` under the older name [`org.glassfish.jaxb`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime):[`jaxb-runtime`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime).

Comment: Which version of java?

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

check available version from here [mvn repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/3.0.1)

Comment: I did that, and know (what I say) another error:

Comment: @Jhon what's another error? Can you give details

Comment: Sorry... this mouse... A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1

Comment: @Jhon, please add an error log in your question

Comment: OK, I´m putting it on the question

Comment: company forlder doesn´t exist: com.company:custom-maven-plugin:1.0  neither this folder: custom-maven-plugin-1.0.pom,

Comment: As far as I'm aware, version 3.x.x uses the new jakarta namespace. It maybe necessary to use a 2.3.x version instead (for the old javax namespace).

Comment: 2.3. what? 1, 2 ? I put 2.3.2 and the errors are on the question

Answer (score 0):

go to your maven repository:

```
.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api
```

and select the right version from there.
For windows the path of maven repository is:

```
C:\Users\<username>\.m2\
```